# Using QGIS Symbol Library with several users?

Tags: qgis, symbology

In ArcGIS you have the possibility to save the style libraray on a server and so many user can access the same library.

Is there a possibility like that in QGIS as well?

I only found the possibility to export the styles using the style manager, but this way it gets confusing as soon as new styles are added to the export.

Where is the symbol library saved anyway?

Answer (score 3):

If your data is in the DB as well, you can save the style directly in the DB. Go to the `layer property`, `style` tab, `style` button and chose `save to DB` (or `load from DB`). The style is then saved in the `public` schema so every user can access it.

[image]